# Python random.uniform not generate 0

Tags: python-3.x, random, uniform

I want to use `random.uniform` to generate a `float` in between say `[-2, 2]`, but not generate `0`, this is how I do it in a loop,

```
from random import uniform

flag = True

while flag:
    if uniform(-2, 2) is not 0:
        flag = False
```

I am wondering is there better way to do it?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more something for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but very briefly:

```
from random import uniform

while True:
    if uniform(-2, 2) != 0.0:
        break
```

is probably the more Pythonic / standard way to do this (standard, as in that this pattern occurs in other languages as well).

It's rare that a `flag` variable is necessary to break out of a (while) loop. Perhaps when using a double loop.

**Note**: I changed your `is not` to `!=`, and your `0` to `0.0` (the latter is more so that it's clear we're comparing a float to a float).
Because you're comparing a `float` to an `int`, so they'll never be the same item. Besides, comparing numbers using `is` is a bad idea:

```
>>> 2*3 is 6  # this may work, but don't rely on it
True
>>> 10*60 is 600  # this obviously doesn't work
False
>>> 0 is 0   # sure, this works...
True
>>> 0.0 is 0  # but this doesn't: float vs int
False
```

---

Of course, to answer the actual question if there are other ways to generate those random numbers: probably a dozen.

- With a list comprehension inside a list comprehension<sup>*</sup>:

  ```
  [val for val in [uniform(-2, 2) for i in range(10)] if val != 0]
  ```
- Using numpy:

  ```
  vals = uniform(-2, 2, 10)
  vals = vals[vals!=0]
  ```

---

<sup>*</sup> I don't want to call it nested, since I feel that belongs to a slightly different double list comprehension.